# Setting a Class(object) to a variable

Tags: java, class, variables, assign

In Java, is it possible to assign a class or class object to a variable?

```
ThatClass obj= a; //a is any constant
```

Instead of `ThatClass obj=new ThatClass();` //where the constructor is called and the integer (or any other value) in that constructor is then called/printed (see below).

```
ThatClass(){

    final int constant=a;
    System.out.println(constant);

}
```

I suspect not, but then again, Java continues to surprise me.

Comment: I don't understand very well what you're trying to do

Comment: What is it you really want to achieve? Your example is not that clear to me neither sorry.

Comment: I suppose that he wants to write the first line, but to get the behavior from the last section. But only @Richard can clarify this question.

Comment: Again, to clarify, I want the first line of code. Can you assign a class and its object to a variable or constant instead of resorting to "new" to call the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can assign class object to another class if the the class whose object you are assigning is a sub type.
For example consider a class

```
class Bird
{
pulic Bird(String name)
{
System.out.println(name);
}
}
```

And now you create a sub class parrot like this

```
class Parrot extends Bird
{
public Parrot()
{
super("Parrot");
}
}
```

Now you create an object of Parrot.

```
Parrot p=new Parrot();
```

You can assign this to Bird

```
Bird b=p;
```

Even if you create a object of Bird like following

```
Bird b1=new Bird("A Bird");
```

You can assign this to another Bird variable like the following

```
Bird b2=b1;
```

If you want to access some fields of the class without creating objects of that class you have to decalre those fields as `static`.

```
class MyClass
{
final static int constant=a;
public static void show()
{
System.out.println(constant);
}
}
```

You can call the `show()` method like the following

```
MyClass.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, Md. I understand this and this is not what I was wondering. I was wondering if a class and object could be set to a variable or a primitive type constant?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
Class classType = String.class;
System.out.println(classType)
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no way you can do this.Basically, You are asking for boxing conversion and java only supports following boxing conversions.

> From type boolean to type Boolean
>
> From type byte to type Byte
>
> From type short to type Short
>
> From type char to type Character
>
> From type int to type Integer
>
> From type long to type Long
>
> From type float to type Float
>
> From type double to type Double
>
> From the null type to the null type

*String is a special case.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7